# A newbish Struts2 question

Tags: java, struts2

Here is the situation.

I have 3 actions
1. action/create_something
2. action/save_something
3. action/preview_something

I start at www.site.com/action/create_something

I fill in some info and submit a form which passes to the save_something action

save_something creates an object foo based on the form inputs. foo now has a field call id ("123"). It then saves some data relevant from foo into the database and forwards to preview_something with the id parameter.

Now I am at www.site.com/action/preview_something?id=123

I take the id and create foo by hitting the database. On the page I display the various fields in foo.

Ok... my question is this:

Is it necessary to pass id to action/preview_something and hit the database again?
Is foo still available to me? Does my object foo still exist in the scope of my action class?

Sorry for the newbishness going on here.

Comment: writing 'n00b' is for n00bs, so next time avoid h4x0r-speech

Comment: How do you forward your action? Anyway - there is a lot of possible solutions, some depends on what you want or what you have (re-set, session, hidden fields,...).

Comment: klez - I am so n00b, I had to use the "new" ^___^

Comment: Trick - The struts.xml looks like

Comment: <action name="create_something" method="create" class="myAction">
            <result name="success">/x.jsp</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirect">/somewhere_else</result>
  </action>

  <action name="save_something" method="save" class="myAction">
   <result name="success" type="redirect">/preview_something</result>
   <result name="input">/e.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">/e.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="preview_something" method="preview" class="myAction">
   <result name="success">/p.jsp</result>
   <result name="input">/p.jsp</result>
  </action>

Comment: I'm sorry. Not sure why stack overflow can't let me put in nicely formatted stuff, or publishes my post after hitting <RET>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, parameter is not available anymore in preview with your case.

Possible solution #1:

Your struts Action can implement [ServletRequestAware](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ServletRequestAware.html). Then you can save your foo object to session in `save()` method and then read it in `preview()`.

Possible solution #2:

In your `save()` you can just return `preview()` and whole scope (object foo, parameters,...) will stay the same as in `save()`.

This would be the easiest way to do it.